# Comparing Next element inside foreach loop in associate array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to access next key-value pair of associate array in php to check whether next key-value pair is same or not.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){

    $b = $value['date'];
    $c = ($key+1)['date']; // As ($key+1) is integer value not an array

    if($b == $c){     
     statement        
    }
}
```

However, This approach is throwing below which seems to be logical.

> ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Is there any way i could find next element inside `foreach` loop in associate array.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'date' => "2019-03-31",
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'date' => "2019-04-02",   
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'date' => "2019-04-02",  
    'a' => '2',
    'b' => '1',
  )
)
```

Comment: `($key+1)` is an integer value, so `($key+1)['date']` will complain. Try `$array[$key + 1][$date]` and be careful for the last iteration.

Comment: Exactly, So How do i compare the?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you're getting `$date` you need `'date'`, and you're not using `$array` anywhere in the `$c` assignment.  It can be shortened, but using your code, just check the `next` element:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $b = $value['date'];
    $c = next($array)['date'] ?? false;
    
    if($b == $c) {     
        echo 'Yes';
    }
}
```

If they are sequential integer keys then you can do it your way, just check that `$key+1` is set:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $b = $value['date'];
    $c = $array[$key+1]['date'] ?? false;
    
    if($b == $c) {     
        echo 'Yes';
    }
}
```